# Usage of "this time so..."

Tags: so

The following is an excerpt from [an NYT article](https://www.nytimes.com/2020/10/24/obituaries/lee-kun-hee-dies-samsung.html?searchResultPosition=2):

> In 1996, Mr. Lee was convicted of bribing the country’s president,
> then pardoned. More than a decade later, he was found guilty of tax
> evasion but given another reprieve, **this time so** he could resume
> lobbying to bring the Winter Olympics to the mountain town of
> Pyeongchang in 2018.

Can anyone please explain the usage of "this time so" here? "So" must be a conjunction since there's no conjunction linking two clauses. What about "this time" then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"This time" and "so" are separate things.
No reason is given for his reprieve of 1996, but **this time**, that is, for this new reprieve, the purpose was **so [that]** he could resume lobbying.

He was given a reprieve so he could resume lobbying.
This time, he was given a reprieve for that purpose.